# One column with multiple foreign keys situation

Tags: sql, database, database-design, sql-server-ce

Here's the deal : this is my first ever database project and I am afraid my solution to this problem isn't quite the best. The database keeps track of different "types" of cooperators. Those types are companies, organisations, employed workers, other "persons" ...

All of those have totally different sets of information, but they all have one in common - contact information. I decided to let user enter what kind of contact information he wants to add to any of the cooperator, whether its e-mail, phone, URL, Fax and so on ...

So I created "`Contacts`" table in which all the contact data for all the cooperators will be put, regardless of what type the cooperator is it.

The `TablesList` is the table that contains the list of cooperator types (Companies, Organisations, Workers)

Each row in the Contacts table must contain `"TableID"` number which identifies what type of the cooperator is it (Company/Worker/Organisation...), and must contain `"RowID"` which identifies what exact company/worker/organisation the contact is about.

The problem that exists it that Contacts table contains foreign keys from 3 other tables in 1 column, which cannot be good. I could remove the relationships and just fill the column with thos ID's without the DBMS knowing about the constrains, but that just doesnt look like a good solution to me, so now I doubt this idea is any good.

What do you suggest ?

Keep in mind that in future there may be some more types of cooperators added if needed (like temp/contract workers, agencies) and Contacts table should be designed to support them too

Thanks in advance !

Btw im using SQL CE and C#

here is the sketch of whats going on :
[image]

**EDIT**

Although it doesnt feel right, I just removed the relationships and it works just fine with my application so far

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your design is over-normalized. You can simplify it by consolidating data into three tables: Companies, Workers and Organisations. It's not going to be normalized but it is much simpler to work with.
Check out http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/07/maybe-normalizing-isnt-normal.html